# deleting data from two tables

Tags: php, mysql

i'm trying to delete data from two tables, the first table(maklumatakaun) has "id" as its primary key and 2nd table(detailakaun) has id as its foreign key. right now my query lead to an error #1064

```
$idURL = $_GET['id'];

$query = "DELETE FROM detailakaun
          INNER JOIN maklumatakaun 
          WHERE maklumatakaun.id = detailakaun.id
          AND id = '$idURL'";
```

i echo the data id with this code

```
<a href="buang_akaun.php?id=<?php echo $id;?>
```

does anybody know how to do this?

EDIT: THE ERROR MESSAGE

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INNER JOIN maklumatakaun WHERE maklumatakaun.id = detailakaun.id AND id = '53'' at line 1

EDIT NEW ERROR
detailakaun has its own A.I id which is idDetail, and inside table detailakaun there are column NoTelefon , KodLokasi and KodJenisAkaun which can have more than one under one identical maklumatakaun.id , now my problem is i can't delete if there's more than one

Comment: Please add the error message.

Comment: Perhaps you have to remove the `'` before and after `$idURL`. Now the **ID** is treated as string, but I think it's rather an integer!

Comment: If the two tables are connected using key, then the deletion of primary key table record will also delete the foreign key table record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you `join` you need an `ON` clause and when joining in a `delete` then you need to specify from which table you delete

```
DELETE m, d
FROM detailakaun d
INNER JOIN maklumatakaun m ON m.id = d.id
WHERE d.id = '$idURL'
```

Comment: let's say i want to update the data,is it the similar way as this?

Comment: Hi sir @juergend i'd found new problem with this code, can you please see my new edit?much appreciated sir

Comment: You missed the `ON m.id = d.id` part

Comment: what do u mean by that sir?

Comment: I am sorry, if you can't compare your query to the one I posted and can't find the difference, then I can't help you. Have a clöose look.

Comment: i did included the ON m.id = d.id part, and it did delete the data but not when theres more than one KodLokasi, KodJenisAkaun and NoTelefon in one maklumatakaun.id inside detailakaun.

Answer (score 0):

You could set up a trigger, so that when you delete a record from one table it deletes the corresponding record from the second table. 
Have a look here : http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/introduction-to-mysql-triggers--net-12226

The advantages are that you only need to execute one query, the downside being there may possibly be a time you want to delete a record from the first table but leave the second table intact

Answer (score 0):

No need to go through any join condition if there are keys as you specified.

```
$query = "DELETE FROM maklumatakaun 
          WHERE id = '$idURL'";
```

This will remove records from both table. But if there's a key exist as you specified, then you can not delete the record from foreign key table unles you remove the relation between two tables.